App center not found in fresh installed Ubuntu Studio 24.04
I have just installed Ubuntu Studio 24.04 (I've never used Ubuntu before), and as I was looking some tutorials on how to install some softwares, I realized that I don't have the "App Center" installed in my PC.
I have tried looking in the app menu (upper left corner) and it is not there. I searched in the "Discover" app, and I found "Software" and "Snap Store". Are those app's the same? or have the same functionality?
I tried sudo apt-get purge snap-store to delete de app and then install it using sudo apt-get install snap-store but it didn't work. I attached a screenshot showing the Konsole  message.


This question is similar to: Has 'Ubuntu Software' been renamed to 'Snap Store'?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

So after a while, I found the solution. Maybe this could help someone.
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2023/09/install-new-app-center-ubuntu-22-04/
What I get of this, is that the "Snap Store" was in my pc, but not up to date, so snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-24.04 solves it.
If you get an error, you need to read the link attached above.

Canonical is decided to ditch the snap completely. Starting from 24.04 snap is not installed in fresh copy. Snap packages are slow use apt instead.
